# Postgres IF table.x > table.y

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

Is it possible to do the following pseudo-code in Postgres 8+ or generic SQL?

```
SELECT table1.a, table1.b ... table1.x, (IF table1.x > table1.y RETURN table1.y ELSE return table1.x AS table1.y), table1.z...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEAST` is a good solution in this case, but the more generic conversion would be the `CASE` statement

```
SELECT 
    table1.a,
    table1.b,
    ... 
    table1.x, 
    CASE WHEN table1.x > table1.y THEN table1.y ELSE table1.x END AS y,
    table1.z
    ...
```

Comment: Which would be the best to use from a performance standpoint? Our DB is *massive* (terabytes), so performance is everything.

Comment: I don't really know, whatever the difference is it is likely measured in nanoseconds and won't matter unless your executing it on a huge result set.

Comment: And I am. This is used in the context of a view, which interfaces with about 300 million rows. In any event, this seems to be the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just re-write the subquery as

`SELECT LEAST(table1.x, table1.y) AS lst`

and then use `lst` everywhere you're currently using `table1.x`?

See the Postgres manual for a description of [`LEAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN14532).